# Youtube iframe returns "Failed to load resource: Frame load interrupted"

Tags: javascript, html, firefox, iframe, safari

I have a Youtube iframe on my website which works fine on Chrome.

But with Firefox and Safari the iframe is not showing and the user is **prompted to download a file** with filename = video_ID with is annoying...

```
<div class="video">
  <iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/v/video_ID" frameborder="0" width="100%"></iframe>
</div>
```

Why did I get this bug and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you are using iframe video instead of "/v/", try "/embed/"

```
https://www.youtube.com/embed/video_ID
```